# Evaluating $\lim_{t\rightarrow 1^-} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\mathrm{Log}(1-t\cos \theta)}{\cos \theta}\ d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $t$ be a real number such that $t\in (-1,1)$.
By considering the unit circle, evaluate
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{d\theta}{1-t\cos\theta}$$
I evaluated this to be equal to
$$\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}.
$$
Then it asks:
Hence, evaluate
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 1^-} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\mathrm{Log}(1-t\cos \theta)}{\cos \theta}\ d\theta.$$

I've triedmanipulating and doing whatever I thought of, but I had no progress.

Comment: Differentiate it under the integral sign with respect to $t$.

Comment: The first expression? I get  
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{-\cos \theta}{(1-t\cos\theta)^2} \ d \theta = -\frac{-4t\pi}{(1-t^2)\sqrt{1-t^2}}
$$

Comment: No, the second.

Comment: Ah cool, I got it!  
So if $f$ was the expression I get  
$$f'(a) = -\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}
$$
but once I integrate I get a constant... how would I get rid of this?

Comment: Then look at $f(0)$.